# JQUERY UI - tabs - load data into a tab, without using IFRAME - Alternative options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-tabs

I currently have a JSP page, containing a Jquery UI based accordion (based on left hand side of the page), that in turn when you select an option in this accordion, it launches a new tab (the tabs are based in the centre of the page)

The content that is loaded into my new tab, is from a JSP page that I have within my project. I am doing this with IFRAME, but I wonder if there is a way to load this JSP's data into the tab without it being an IFRAME?

This JSP contains a dynamic data, images and text.

It would be cleaner if it was output displayed within the tab itself and not an IFRAME - the usability for this isn't great.

What alternative options to IFRAME could I have for doing this?

Comment: You could use any of jquery's ajax methods: $(selector).load, $.get, $.post, $.ajax

Comment: If I answered your question please click the checkmark next to my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function, it is very simple and easy to use.

A good example of this can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/TR2kn/ (click expand)

A simpler example: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/TR2kn/1/

But, please be warned that this cannot load data across domains so the data must be on your server (there are some workarounds but they get complicated)!